# I was a judge in a science competition, should I include that my resume

Tags: cv

I served as a judge in a science competition for high, middle and elementary school students. I am confused if I can put this activity in my resume. Also, I do not know in which section I need to include if I can put this on my resume. 
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, if your CV is a bit skimpy at this stage in your career.  You could put it under Outreach, which is very up and coming, or Volunteer Experience.  Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107320/32436

Comment: I wouldn’t make it a large part, but it’s certainly worthy of mention if you’re applying for any position that requires teaching or outreach activities. Even in straight non-teachin roles, it helps flesh out your character, but I’d leave it off a one-pager, but include in a longer resume.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments and answers. It helped me to clear my mind on this. I just had my MS degree, so I am trying to make my resume more appealing. I was just trying to figure out if it would be awkward to put this activity on my resume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is this resume for?

If it's for a job judging science competitions, put it on there.

If it's for a job herding goats in Peru, leave it off.

Anything in the middle, use your experience in judgement to decide if it's relevant.

Comment: While I did smile reading this, I think it would have been better to ask this (what is the resume for)  as a comment. OP probably wants the expertise of others to help decide, but left out a critical piece of information.

Comment: @Bitwise, indeed, I was originally going to write the whole thing as a comment but it got too long.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, such activities would be listed under "service activities" in a CV or "other professional activities" in a resume. However, I would argue that such activities be limited to "ongoing" professional activities. Something you did just once probably should not be listed on your resume; an activity you do year after year probably should.